# Working with Access 97 DBs natively

Tags: microsoft-access

When I open an Access 97 DB in Access 2003 it requires me to convert it before I can make changes. My question is what is the last/latest version of Access which can work with Access 97 DBs natively, i.e. without the need to convert to work on it.

(To note, the DB must remain in 97 format to be compatible with a 3rd party application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access 97 was written with [Jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) 3.5, and Access 2000-2007 use Jet 4.0.

Because of this, the last version of access that can read Access 97 databases without modification is Access 97.